# Creating Scheduled Task from Group Policy. Can't write to network share?

Tags: group-policy, file-permissions, scheduled-task

I am using NinitePro and group policy to deploy and update software on our small network of 150 Win 7 and WinXP machines. I am roughly following these instructions:
http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/15072-easy-cheap-third-party-patch-management

My setup is as follows. I have a network share I use for deploying software on the network. I created two folders there; bin for a batch file and the NinitePro.exe, and var for Ninite cache files and logs from the batch file.

I then created a gpo linked it to the OU containing my test lab and used security filtering to limit the deployment to just my test lab. In said GPO I created a scheduled task under Computer\preferences\Control Panel\Scheduled Tasks. It just a plain old scheduled task since I have XP clients. I did not specify a user and password under the "Run As:" section so the task runs as NT Authority:System.

This is working so far as Ninite is being called and is updating and installing software, however it is not able to write logs or cache files to the var folder on the network.

How can I set the permissions on the network share so my batch file called from this scheduled task and running as system can write to a network share. Or how should I do this if I have it all wrong. Hope this makes sense. Please ask questions if you need clarification.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Processes running as SYSTEM on domain member computers access network resources as the computer's Active Directory account. Make sure your shared folder is writable by the computer accounts (like, say, "Domain Computers") and you'll be good to go.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you! I set the permissions so only system, administrators, and domain computers have access and it seems to be working fine. :) Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, I should add that this isn't necessarily the best / easiest way to use Ninite Pro.

Ninite Pro has a 'Remote' mode, so you can simply run one batch file on a server and push all the applications and updates to the clients.  You can select OUs to push to etc.

eg:

```
C:\Apps\Maintenance\Niniteone.exe /remote ad:OU=MainOffice,OU=CompanyMachines,OU=Computers,DC=domain,DC=local /select "your" "list" "of" "apps" /silent \\server\share\NiniteLogs\%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~0,2%_Ninite-log.csv
```

And then you won't need network shares and GPOs to deploy.  You can just schedule that to run on the server.